# First row not detected with R

Tags: r

I have my data in xls file.I try to read like this

```
> df = read.xls ("natgas.xls")
```

Output

```
df
    Dec.2007 X2399154
1   Jan-2008  2733970
2   Feb-2008  2503421
3   Mar-2008  2278151
4   Apr-2008  1823867
5   May-2008  1576387
6   Jun-2008  1604249
7   Jul-2008  1708641
8   Aug-2008  1682924
9   Sep-2008  1460924
10  Oct-2008  1635827
```

Everything is OK,except the first line.
When I index second column

```
> df[,2]
  [1] 2733970 2503421 2278151 1823867 1576387 1604249 1708641 1682924 1460924
```

the first value is missing.

How to solve this?

Comment: Your first row is considered as header. Which package are you using? Most of the packages have parameter like header, which you can set to false and the first row will be not considered as header.

Comment: @bouncyball Thanks,works perfect you can add answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to add `header = FALSE` to your `read.xls` call (which seems to come from the [**`gdata`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gdata/gdata.pdf) package):

```
df1 <- read.xls("natgas.xls", header = FALSE)
```